# Create Directories From String Array

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mkdir

I have an array of directory names. I wanna create directories from the array. This is my code.

```
WATCHED_MOVIE_LIST=("Tenet", "Inception", "Interstellar", "Arrival", "Escape Room")
mkdir ${WATCHED_MOVIE_LIST[*]}
```

This code will create directories like this.

```
Tenet
Inception
Interstellar
Arrival
Escape
Room
```

But `Escape Room` is a single name. It must create a single folder called 'Escape Room'. However, I want to create directories like this

```
Tenet
Inception
Interstellar
Arrival
Escape Room
```

How do I do this in 2 lines of code? (One line is better)

Comment: One problem:
```sh
WATCHED_MOVIE_LIST=("Tenet", "Inception", "Interstellar", "Arrival", "Escape Room")
mkdir "_idk/${WATCHED_MOVIE_LIST[@]}"
```
not work, but i think you want like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426794/541257

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do that by doing small changes to my code.

```
WATCHED_MOVIE_LIST=("Tenet", "Inception", "Interstellar", "Arrival", "Escape Room")
mkdir "${WATCHED_MOVIE_LIST[@]}" 
# '*' replaced with '@'
# Added double quotations to ${WATCHED_MOVIE_LIST[@]}
```

This code can do my work. Thanks